Very simple slash command failing with "This interaction failed"
I'm trying to make a simple Discord bot with pycord that includes slash commands, after porting away from text-based commands.
I've made the below simple-as-possible code, yet every time I run the slash command no matter what, I get a "This interaction failed" error, but no errors in the command line.
on_ready() calls, and I've added the bot to my test server with applications.command and bot access as an administrator, yet it's still failing.
What could I possibly be doing wrong?
import discord

bot = discord.Bot()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Online as {0.user}'.format(bot))

@bot.slash_command(name="hello", description="Say hello to the bot")
async def hello(ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
    await ctx.respond("Hey!")

Pycord, macOS Sonoma, Python 3

I could not reproduce the issue on my side, I assume that you are correctly running bot.run(TOKEN). Could you please enable debug logging with import logging and logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO) at the top of your code, and edit your messages with the info logs?

@Paillat Just tested and the logger doesn't spit out an error (or anything) when I run a failed slash command. Also I believe my token code's correct, I was using it to send messages over discord.py (called with bot.run('TOKEN')).

I still have no idea what happened, but I made a new bot and it worked perfectly with the same code.

That's great but this means that: your code was not the problem (it was intents), & this post will be closed.

I don't see how this means the post should be closed, nor why my post is being downvoted now that I've found the problem? This is still a solution to an issue people have and will face. There's approved solutions on countless SO threads that involve clearing caches or making new projects - def not code related.

It's not reproducible and was caused by something unrelated to code. Questions unrelated to code are fine, but we can't reproduce this one at all (which makes it entirely useless to future people)
